# Calculate a Rate and group it

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe with the columns state and runtime

```
id state        runtime
1  successful   25
2  successful   30
3  failed       30
4  failed       35
```

I want to calculate a success rate for every runtime in a new dataframe to plot the data later.
Success rate is successful projects divided by all projects

```
runtime  success_rate
25       1
30       0.5
35       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tidy solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(runtime) %>%
  summarise(
    success_rate = sum[state=="successful"]/n()
  )
```